# Which part is this round window frame?

Tags: part-identification

Please identify the round white semi-circle piece in [this window](https://www.flickr.com/photos/28192677@N06/16393644342/in/contacts/).  It kind of looks like a mudflap, but I think it's bigger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a Wheel Arch (mudguard) piece, [#50745](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50745&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)

[image]

Comment: The confusion may come from its age; newer sets seem to use a smaller one (part 98282) <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98282#T=C>

Comment: @RSchulz Out of 11 sets using 50745 element in 2021, 6 sets have it in White. I'd say this wheel arch (50745) is still pretty common these days.

Comment: Huh. Only 10 of the smaller one in 2021. I just assumed when they changed the mold, they'd go all in.